# Play live stream on twilio hold

Tags: twilio

I have a need to play LIVE audio to enqueued twilio calls (instead of playing hold music from an mp3 file for instance).

I've tried pointing the hold music to a live mp3 stream (icecast), which didn't work.

The only thing I can think of is to start a conference, put a call into it that is sending the audio I need to be played on hold, and then on-hold calls are placed (muted) into that conference.

Doesn't seem like best way, and I'd like to avoid conference costs though (there are millions of minutes per month of on-hold time).

Is there a more elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I am aware this is not possible with `<Play>`. When you give Twilio an mp3 file to play it first downloads and caches the file (if the headers allow for it). When working with mp3 files Twilio expects an existing file and a finite file size.

I think using a conference, or a series of direct one to one calls, to play the stream as you suggested is likely the best solution. If you do have millions of minutes per month then I recommend you get in touch with the [Twilio sales team](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) who might be able to make those minutes more affordable.

Comment: Figured as much. Just a side note: I WAS eventually able to get a live mp3 stream to play from Icecast during enqueue by adjusting some things on my end (and removing .mp3 from the live stream URL).Interestingly, the audio stops playing (goes silent) for about 5 seconds exactly every 30 seconds. I guessed (and you confirm) that's probably because it doesn't know what to do with the live stream data. Too bad - so close, but yet so far...seems like Twilio could make this work with a minor tweak. Thanks!

Comment: That is interesting! But yeah, I'm sure it's because Twilio was built to try to download and cache mp3 files and it's just not sure what it's doing with the stream. I'm fascinated by what you're actually building here. If you can share it with me, drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com

Comment: Hi Roger, Amazing you got it to work, i tried and removed the .mp3 from the icecast stream mount point, but still not working, did you remember doing anything else?